# PayPal - Forcing PayPal to use county list

Tags: paypal

I have a client who wants it so the user does not have to signup to purchase items on the site and everything is processed via PayPal. My client cannot send out to *Greese or the US and I was wondering how I can only allow certain people to process a payment if they are from a certain group of countries (or not from).

regards

Phil

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll need to do something on your side to prevent those transactions from going through.